# Isometry groups of symmetric spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetric-spaces

Let $M=G/K$ be a symmetric space where $G=\mathrm{Isom}(M)$ and $K$ is the isotropy at some point $o\in M$. Moreover, let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}\oplus\mathfrak{p}$ be the Cartan decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}$, the Lie algebra of $G$. Then, $\mathfrak{k}$ is the Lie algebra of $K$ and we can identify $\mathfrak{p}$ with $T_o M$, the tangent space of $M$ at $o$. Furthermore, let  $\varphi\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$. I have the following questions:

1. If $\varphi$ preserves $\mathfrak{p}$, then $\varphi$ corresponds to an element of $K$.  Can $\varphi$ still induce an isometry of $M$ if it does not preserve $\mathfrak{p}$?
2. Is there a relationship between the number of connected components of $G$ and $\mathrm{Out}(\mathfrak{g})$, the outer automorphisms of $\mathfrak{g}$?
3. Where could I find a reference containing a list of $\mathrm{Out}(\mathfrak{g})$ for each real simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$?
4. Where could I find a reference containing a list of the full isometry group of each symmetric space and the number of connected components of each of them?

Comment: For 3 there's a paper by Gundogan with such a list (assuming you mean the group of connected components of the *Lie group* $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$.

Comment: I think your questions are answered in Loos, Ottmar
Symmetric spaces. II: Compact spaces and classification. W. A. Benjamin, Inc., New York-Amsterdam 1969 viii+183 pp. Especially check  chap. 7, section 4.

Comment: See also the book: Helgason, Sigurdur.
Differential geometry, Lie groups, and symmetric spaces. 
Corrected reprint of the 1978 original. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 34. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2001.

Comment: See Table V on page 518 in Helgason's book.

Comment: Also, take a look at Ravi Shankar's thesis paper: https://math.ou.edu/~shankar/papers/paper_thesis.pdf (It focuses on the case that G/H is a positively curved homogeneous space, but many insights there are useful here too.)